# Optimize query with inner queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm developing an application that visualizes data from a MySQL database, using PHP. It is about logs in Battlefield 4 of who kills whom. I want to list the number of kills with a specific weapon in descending order, subdivided by a list showing who that person killed, also in descending order.

Database structure:

[image: BF4 Database Structure]

My PHP code to visualize it on a tabel:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "bf4", "bf4") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("bf4") or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT p.playerId AS pid, p.playerName AS name,
    COUNT(`playerkills`.`id`) AS amount FROM `playerkills`
    JOIN players p ON playerkills.playerId = p.playerId
    WHERE weaponId = 9 GROUP BY playerkills.playerId ORDER BY amount DESC;")
    or die(mysql_error());

$i = 0;
$lastamount = -1;
$offset = 0;
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    if ($lastamount != $result->amount) {
        $i += 1 + $offset;
        $offset = 0;
    } else {
        $offset++;
    }
    echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td><td>".$result->name."</td><td>".$result->amount."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><th></th><th>Target</th><th>Kills</th></tr>";

    $query_inner = mysql_query("SELECT p.playerName AS name,
        COUNT(`playerkills`.`id`) AS amount FROM `playerkills`
        JOIN players p ON playerkills.targetId = p.playerId 
        HERE weaponId = 9 AND playerkills.playerId = '{$result->pid}'
        GROUP BY playerkills.targetId ORDER BY amount DESC;");

    while ($result_inner = mysql_fetch_object($query_inner)) {
        echo "<tr><td></td><td>".$result_inner->name."</td><td>".$result_inner->amount."</td></tr>";
    }
    $lastamount = $result->amount;
}
mysql_close($con) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Now comes the extra requirement though, which could potentially make it a lot more interesting: It should only show the subdivided data (the inner query), if the website user asks for it (indicated by clicking on a column, I'll implement that in Javascript later). Is there a way now to even optimize the query further?

As last an example of the code running on a filled database:

[image: BF4 example]

I hope the question is formalized clearly, if you still have questions, then I'll update this post accordingly.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to optimize this code? Then you might be better off at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @kingkero I think it is wrong to issue the big number of queries I am doing now, best would be to pull everything in one query I think if possible.

Comment: in my experience, two queries are better than using sub queries in most scenarios (I always benchmark my s**t). There is/was a bug inMySql that there was no index usage in inner queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying the database within the loop is not good, you create too many queries that way. You can get the same results with two queries with different groupings.  Each of the two queries should join the playerkills table with weapons table and with the players table.

By grouping the first query by playerId would give you the total kills of that player. Then by grouping the second query by playerId,targetId would give you the kills for each of the target players.

For example *(not tested)*,

**query1 - total result for each player**

```
SELECT p.playerId AS pid, p.playerName AS player, COUNT(*) AS kills
FROM playerkills pk
JOIN players p ON p.playerId = pk.playerId
WHERE weaponId = 9 
GROUP BY p.playerId,p.playerName ORDER BY kills DESC;
```

**query2 - detailed results of targets**

```
SELECT p2.playerName AS target, COUNT(*) AS kills 
FROM playerkills pk
JOIN players p ON p.playerId = pk.playerId
JOIN players p2 ON p2.playerId = pk.targetId
WHERE weaponId = 9
GROUP BY p.playerId,p2.playerId,p2.playerName ORDER BY p.playerId, kills DESC;
```

The second query could be called only if the user asks for detailed info, as you indicated, in that case you can add something like `AND p.playerId= $pid` after the `where` clause. In this case p.playerId is not required in `order by` as you will only get results of a specific player and you will simply iterate through them.

Comment: Could you explain why you have for example in query 1 you have `GROUP BY p.playerId, p.playerName`, does grouping by `p.playerId` further optimize the query? And for the rest I think lazy loading is the most acceptable solution in this case as I do not want to put too much stress on the server.

Comment: @skiwi Both p.playerId and pk.playerId should be indexed as the one is a primary key and the other foreign key, so whether p.playerId is used or pk.playerId should make no difference. The p.playerName has been added in the group by in order to also use it inside the select. I know mysql doesn't really bother you can put whatever in the select, but it is correct and makes sense to add only columns participating in the group by. As far as lazy loading, i agree, it is better to simply retrieve and server the results only if they are asked.

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer to this will be very long.

I suggest you to give a try with the "WITH ROLLUP" modifier.

The With ROLLUP will sure optimize the sql side job but required some tricks on the php side.
You should put the result in a JSON object and then manage you html tables with javascript intead of statically create them php side.

If there is too much datas do manage the result on the javascript, then you should change approach.

You first need a PHP page tha produce JSON for you details (a webservice, call it GetDetails.php?someParams). Then your main page should do just the outer query and place a link on each row to exapand it. 
Expand it means call a AJAX script that will queries the GetDetails.php? and via DOM add the new rows in the table.

Hope this helps

Comment: Here you can find the documentation about it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: @melc doing two queries do not optimize the job. Both query aggregate the same amount of rows, only result size are different. Doing a single group by with rollup you get both results at once at the cost of one.

Comment: group by with rollup is a fine option (+1) if the user wants both results possibly better optimised than two queries. However, two queries allow for lazy loading of the details results.

Comment: Both approaches will certainly optimize the current solution.

Comment: It seems like ordering by `amount` is not possible in this situation when using `WITH ROLLUP`, I cannot seem to geet my head around to make a correct query with using `WITH ROLLUP`, though I do get how it should be working.